# Change function on-click using if in the handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, ractivejs

I have a boolean variable that is set in the JS and I want to change the function a button calls when an on-click event is fired. Below are the two ways I've tried.

```
<button type="button" {{#if variable}}on-click="funcOne"{{else}}on-click="funcTwo"{{/if}}>Click Me</button>

<button type="button" on-click="{{#if variable}}funcOne{{else}}funcTwo{{/if}}>Click me</button>
```

Is this not possible in the handlebars, would I instead have to call one function that checks the variable and then call one of the two functions from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is something we have an [open issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1270) for - currently, 'conditional directives' (i.e. directives such as `on-click`) aren't supported inside mustache sections.

There are two different ways we can make this work. The first is with *proxy events*:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'main',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        variable: true
    }
});

ractive.on({
    funcOne: function () { alert( 'one' ); },
    funcTwo: function () { alert( 'two' ); }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ractive/0.7.3/ractive-legacy.min.js"></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' checked='{{variable}}'/> variable ({{variable}})
    </label>
    
    <button type="button" on-click="{{#if variable}}funcOne{{else}}funcTwo{{/if}}">Click me</button>
</script>
```

The `click` event is translated into either a `funcOne` event or a `funcTwo` event depending on `variable` - we just need to listen for that event with `ractive.on`, the same as you might listen for the `click` event with `node.addEventListener`.

The alternative approach is to call a method directly. You can't choose a method conditionally (i.e. `on-click='{{#if variable}}funcOne(){{else}}funcTwo(){{/if}}'`), but you can do it using regular JavaScript:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'main',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        variable: true
    },
    funcOne: function () { alert( 'one' ); },
    funcTwo: function () { alert( 'two' ); },
    callMethod: function ( name ) {
        this[name]();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ractive/0.7.3/ractive-legacy.min.js"></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' checked='{{variable}}'/> variable ({{variable}})
    </label>
    
    <button type="button" on-click="callMethod(variable?'funcOne':'funcTwo')">Click me</button>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich for such an in depth answer

Comment: Could you also use one on click event that then does the if statement to determine whether or not to call funcOne or funcTwo? Effectively, pushing the logic from the view back to the view model?

Comment: @BryanRay you mean like `<button on-click='foo()'>`, where `foo` is something like `this.get('variable') ? this.funcOne() : this.funcTwo()`? Sure, no reason why not